# Understanding core.logic !=

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I would expect the following expression to return a number of results, each of which consists of two cons cells, where the two cons cells are not equivalent. However, it returns 0 results. Why am I getting no results?

```
(run* [c1 c2] 
  (fresh [lx ly x1 y1 x2 y2] 
    (== lx [1 2])
    (== ly [4 5])
    (membero x1 lx)
    (membero x2 lx) 
    (membero y1 ly)
    (membero y2 ly)
    (conso x1 y1 c1)
    (conso x2 y2 c2)
    (!= c1 c2)))
```

Examples of expected results:

- `[(1 . 4) (2 . 5)]`
- `[(1 . 4) (1 . 5)]`
- `[(2 . 4) (2 . 5)]`

I would not expect it to return a result like `[(1 . 4) (1 . 4)]` where both spots in each cons are equal.

If I remove the `(!= c1 c2)` portion, I get 16 results, including those where both cons are the same.

I get the results I expect if I replace `(!= c1 c2)` with:

```
(conde
  ((!= x1 x2))
  ((!= y1 y2)))
```

which should do the same thing, but explicitly checks the two cells.

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Why does the first expression have results, but the second one doesn't, even though the only differences are seemingly equivalent?

Comment: I edited my question to make my question more clear.

Comment: Ooops conde, membero, and all that are part of Clojure core logic. I'll have to look those up.

Comment: Those functions are part of clojure/core.logic. The source is available [on Github](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/logic.clj).

Comment: It is giving me 12 results. Try it with latest core.logic from github. Work is going on core.logic and hence there are many fixed going on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a valid core.logic program. You cannot use `conso` where the tail is not proper. miniKanren in Scheme will let you do this, but the behavior is undefined for core.logic. I've amended the docstring for `conso` to reflect this. A working program:

```
(run* [c1 c2] 
  (fresh [lx ly x1 y1 x2 y2] 
    (== lx [1 2])
    (== ly [4 5])
    (membero x1 lx)
    (membero x2 lx) 
    (membero y1 ly)
    (membero y2 ly)
    (== [x1 y1] c1)
    (== [x2 y2] c2)
    (!= c1 c2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The poster that said you can't use conso like this is correct.  Here's the docstring:

> A relation where l is a collection, such that a is the first of l
>   and d is the rest of l. If ground d must be bound to a proper tail.

You should make a proper list using `(== [x1 y1] c1)` and `(== [x2 y2] c2)` or `(conso x1 [y1] c1)` and `(conso x2 [y2] c2)`.